# How can i disable cache in drupal 8 for some time?

Tags: php, caching, drupal-8

Currently, I am working on a project on a popular PHP framework Drupal Version 8. In the framework, Browse cache is enabled by default. So when I am making any change in any file, it needs to clear the cache from the backend to reflect the change that I have made. This is simply increasing our development time as it is taking a long time to clear the cache. I have not found any way to do this. If it is known to anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914

You basically need to access your example.settings.local.php settings and go to the section that starts with disable the render cache and uncomment the settings variable for that section:

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```